# Masonry JS plug-in - Chrome / Firefox issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, cross-browser, jquery-masonry

I am attempting to use the Masonry plug-in to replicate a 'Pinterst' display.  Everything is displaying great in Safari, but things often appear a mess in Chrome and Firefox.  I am unsure on how to approach remedying this.  Below is the JavaScript used to call the jQuery Masonry plug-in code.

Thanks for the help!

```
<script>
  $("#container").imagesLoaded(function(){
    $('#container').masonry({
        itemSelector: '.item',
        columnWidth: 240,
        isFitWidth: true
    });
    $("#container").infinitescroll({
        navSelector: "span.page a",            
        nextSelector: "span.next a",    
        itemSelector: '.item'          
      },
      // trigger Masonry as a callback
      function( newElements ) {
        var $newElems = $( newElements );       
        $("#container").imagesLoaded(function(){
          $("#container").masonry( 'appended', $newElems )
        });
      });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: The actual site can be viewed at furnishlyst.com

Answer (score 0):

You're binding on imagesLoaded in a nested way. This means that you're not binding the second function until after the event has been fired already.